# Add labels to upset plot, so the values of intersection would be visible along the number of intersection

Tags: r, upsetr, upsetplot

I have multiple character vectors containing gene names found in some analyzed samples (cells). I would like to compare those sets and figure out whether they have some genes in common (and if they do, I would like to know how many and which genes are overlapping between which sets). My goal is to visualize those data in some informative, reader-friendly manner. I decided to use upset plot, since the venn diagram for so many groups would be too messy.

Here is a dummy dataset containing 4 groups (although my real life data are >10):

```
lista <- list(cell_1 = c("Tmed9", "Lrp1", "Dlx3", "Igfbp2", "Ubl3", "Rab5b", 
"Rab1b", "Ppm1g", "Drap1", "Matr3", "Exosc2", "Fstl1", "Rpl38", 
"Sarnp", "Ppp4c", "Znhit1", "Fam20a", "Cnbp", "Rpl27", "Grb14", 
"Gng11", "Cyfip1"), cell_2 = c("Tmed9", "Clec2d", "Cd74", "Uba5", 
"Lars2", "mt-Co1", "mt-Co3", "Lax1", "Cnbp", "Insig1", "Eaf2", 
"Pcbp2", "Top1", "Gm2000", "Rexo2", "Hnrnpa0", "Cox17", "Grk2", 
"Vmp1", "1810037I17Rik", "Pim1", "Lmnb1", "Gm9844", "Eif4a3"), 
    cell_3 = c("Rab1b", "Lars2", "Rpl38", "Cnbp", "H2aj", "M6pr", 
    "B2m", "Il10ra", "H2-D1", "mt-Co3", "Cd74", "Pld4", "Ptp4a2", 
    "Pomp", "mt-Co1", "Ivns1abp", "Plac8", "Myl12b", "Rpl27", 
    "Eif3i", "Csk", "Rgs2", "mt-Cytb"), cell_4 = c("Spon1", "Phactr1", 
    "Lrp1", "Tmed9", "Cit", "Fads2", "Igfbp2", "Camk2b", "Ubqln2", 
    "Ddn", "Kifc2", "Ripor1", "Ubl3", "Rab1b", "Ppm1g", "Samd4b", 
    "Lrrc4b", "Cmtm5", "Git1", "Rph3a", "Matr3", "Pgp", "Fstl1", 
    "Nrgn"))
```

I want to use this nested list of gene names to create an upset plot in R.

Here is my example code:

```
library(UpSetR)
UpSetR::upset(fromList(lista), order.by = "freq",nintersects = NA,nsets = 4)
```

Which produces this figure:
[image]

I would like to incorporate there, somehow, the actual gene labels, for instance "Tmed9" which contribute to the respective intersections, so I would not only know how many items are common between which sets, but also know which elements exactly are shared between the sets.

I did not find similar question on SO, did not find clues in the vignette nor on Github, so I am posting my question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an excellent idea. I do not know if this is possible using UpSetR, but if you are willing to try [ComplexUpset](https://github.com/krassowski/complex-upset/), you can achieve the following result:

[image]

First, we need to define `fromList` equivalent, lets call it `from_list`:

```
from_list <- function(list_data) {
    members = unique(unlist(list_data))
    data.frame(
        lapply(list_data, function(set) members %in% set),
        row.names=members,
        check.names=FALSE
    )
}
```

Then we need to add the gene names; here I will re-use the row names shortening the longest gene name so it fits nicely:

```
matrix = from_list(lista)
matrix$gene_name = rownames(matrix)
matrix[matrix$gene_name == '1810037I17Rik', 'gene_name'] = 'RIKEN'
head(matrix)
```

> ```
> A data.frame: 6 × 5
>        cell_1 cell_2  cell_3  cell_4  gene_name
>        <lgl>  <lgl>   <lgl>   <lgl>   <chr>
> Tmed9  TRUE   TRUE    FALSE   TRUE    Tmed9
> Lrp1   TRUE   FALSE   FALSE   TRUE    Lrp1
> Dlx3   TRUE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   Dlx3
> Igfbp2 TRUE   FALSE   FALSE   TRUE    Igfbp2
> Ubl3   TRUE   FALSE   FALSE   TRUE    Ubl3
> Rab5b  TRUE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   Rab5b
> ```

And finally, it's time to plot! We will swap the default `base_annotations` with a custom layer which re-uses `intersection_size`, adding ggplot2' `geom_text` layer:

```
library(ComplexUpset)
upset(
    matrix,
    intersect=c('cell_1', 'cell_2', 'cell_3', 'cell_4'),
    base_annotations=list(
        'Intersection size'=(
            intersection_size(
                bar_number_threshold=1,
                color='grey9',
                fill='grey80'
            )
            + geom_text(
                mapping=aes(label=gene_name),
                position=position_stack(),
                na.rm=TRUE,
                vjust=1.3
            )
        )
    ),
    width_ratio=0.15,
    height_ratio=1/4
)
```

For more complex-upset customization see [examples here](https://krassowski.github.io/complex-upset/articles/Examples_R.html).

Or without the bars in background:

```
library(ComplexUpset)
upset(
    matrix,
    intersect=c('cell_1', 'cell_2', 'cell_3', 'cell_4'),
    base_annotations=list(
        'Intersection size'=(
            ggplot()
            + aes(
                x=intersection,
                y=!!ComplexUpset:::get_mode_presence('distinct'),
                label=gene_name
            )
            + geom_text(
                position=position_stack(),
                na.rm=TRUE,
                vjust=1.3
            )
        )
    ),
    width_ratio=0.15,
    height_ratio=1/4
)
```

Second improvement: if one needs to fit an occasionally longer label, they can replace `geom_text` with `ggfittext::geom_bar_text` as follows:

```
            + ggfittext::geom_bar_text(
                mapping=aes(label=gene_name),
                min.size=0,
                position='stack',
                contrast=FALSE,
                vjust=1.1,
            )
```

[image]

Disclaimer: I am the author of complex-upset.

Comment: awesome! I was writing a comment in which I wanted to ask if there is a way to remove background grid, but you were first with your edit. I think with gene labels upset is more informative for biologists.